# Load more button does not load anything when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've added a load more button to my front page.  The button will load more posts after every 15 posts.  I've added all of the necessary code, however when I click the button nothing loads.  Does anyone have a solution?  Or if there is just a better and more efficient way to load more posts I would love other solutions.  I've been trying to get this to work for weeks, and I just can't get it.

front-page.php

```html
<?php 
/* 
* Template Name: 
*/ 

get_header(); 
get_template_part ('inc/carousel'); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( [ 
'posts_per_page' => 15, 
'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) 
] ); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?> 
<div id="ajax"> 
<?php 
$i = 0; 
$j = 0; 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); 

if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?> 
<div class="row"> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>> 
<div class="large-front-container"> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
</div> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?> 
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?> 
<div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
</div> 
</article> 
</div> 

<?php 

} else { // Small posts ?> 
<?php if($j % 2 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
    <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
    </div>

</article> 

<?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?> 
<?php 
} 
$i++; 
}?> 

</div> 
<?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) { ?>
    <button id=load-more>load more</button>
<?php
} 
} 
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') { 
echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>'; 
} 
get_footer();
```

functions.php

```html
//LOAD MORE
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_more', 'load_more' );

  function load_more() {
    if ( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'load_more' ){
      $loopFile        = $_POST['loop_file'];
      $paged           = $_POST['page_no'];
      $posts_per_page  = $_POST['posts_per_page'];

      $args = array('paged' => $paged,
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page);

      $query = new WP_Query($args);

      get_template_part( $loopFile );
    }

    wp_reset_query();

    exit;
   }
```

loop.php

```html
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          $the_query->the_post();
<?php 
$i = 0; 
$j = 0; 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); 

if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?> 
<div class="row"> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>> 
<div class="large-front-container"> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
</div> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?> 
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?> 
<div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
</div> 
</article> 
</div> 

<?php 

} else { // Small posts ?> 
<?php if($j % 2 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
    <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
    </div>

</article> 

<?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?> 
<?php 
} 
$i++; 
}?>  
        }
?>
```

js

```html
 // AJAX to grab more posts, wrap with a vanilla javascript or
  // jQuery click event function.
  function loadMorePosts(pageNumber, postsPerPage) {
    var query = 'action=load_more&page_no=' + pageNumber + 
        '&loop_file=loop&posts_per_page=' + postsPerPage;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: query,
        success: function(response){
            // handle response
        }
    });
}
```

EDITED JS

```html
 function loadMorePosts(pageNumber, postsPerPage) {

  var query = 'action=load_more&page_no=' + pageNumber + 
    '&loop_file=loop&posts_per_page=' + postsPerPage;

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: query,
    success: function(response){
        // handle response
    }
  });
}
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#load-more').on('click', function(){
    loadMorePosts(pageNumber, postsPerPage)
  })
})
```

Comment: How are you attaching your loadMorePosts function to your load-more button?

Comment: You should not use snipplets if the code can not run on its own.... In all the code  I do not see where you call loadMorePosts

Comment: I had some help creating this.  How would I call loadMorePosts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that you have not attached the loadMorePosts function to an event listener on your button. Since your button has the id 'load-more', you can do the following:

```
function loadMorePosts(pageNumber, postsPerPage) {

  var query = 'action=load_more&page_no=' + pageNumber + 
    '&loop_file=loop&posts_per_page=' + postsPerPage;

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: query,
    success: function(response){
        // handle response
    }
  });
}
$('#load-more').on('click', function(){
  loadMorePosts(pageNumber, postsPerPage)
})
```

Some caveats. I don't know how you're retrieving the pageNumber and postsPerPage values.

This answer assumes you're loading your script after the html has finished loading. If that is not the case, you'll need to do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#load-more').on('click', function(){
    loadMorePosts(pageNumber, postsPerPage)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  Unfortunately, it still does not work.  When you press the button no posts load.  I've added my edited js to my question.

Comment: Check your network tab in your chrome developer tools. Are you seeing the appropriate Ajax call there? How are you obtaining the pageNumber/postsPerPage?

Comment: On my front-page.php I have 'posts_per_page' => 15,

Comment: @user6738171 That's a php variable. The JS is unaware of the php variables unless you use the php to write some js that makes it aware.